# How do I set the shared extended properties on an event that I am not the organizer of?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am trying to set shared extended properties on an event where I am an attendee and not the owner but I keep getting a 403 error.

Based on the documentation here -> https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/extended-properties#visibility, it says that attendees can edit shared extended properties of an event.

The error I am getting is

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "forbiddenForNonOrganizer",
    "message": "Shared properties can only be changed by the organizer of the event."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Shared properties can only be changed by the organizer of the event."
 }
}
```

Has anyone else been able to do this? Or is the documentation wrong?